# Why my function check javascript only works on the first pop up modal?

Tags: javascript

```js
function checkID() {

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "editclientecex.php",
    data: 'clientid=' + $("#   clientid").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#check_id").html(data);
    },
    error: function() {}
  });
}


function checkName() {

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "editclientecex.php",
    data: 'name=' + $("#name").val().ucwords(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#check_name").html(data);
    },
    error: function() {}
  });
}

function checkContact() {

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "editclientecex.php",
    data: 'contactno=' + $("#contactno").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#check_contact").html(data);
    },
    error: function() {}
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="edit<?php echo $row['contactno']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" />
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h1>EDIT CLIENT</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <?php
                        $edit=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM client WHERE contactno='".$row['contactno']."'");
                        $editrow=mysqli_fetch_array($edit);
                        
                        $type = $editrow['type'];
        
                    ?>
      <form method="post" action="editclientecex.php?contactno=<?php echo $editrow['contactno']; ?>">
        <table width="342" class="addclitable">
          <tr>
            <td width="107" class="modal-table">ID:</td>
            <td width="315"><input type="text" name="clientid" value="<?php echo $editrow['id']; ?>" id="clientid" oninput="checkID()" required/>
              <span id="check_id"></span></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="modal-table">PHASE:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="phase" value="<?php echo $editrow['phase']; ?>" required/></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="modal-table">NAME:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $editrow['name']; ?>" id="name" oninput="checkName()" required/></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="modal-table">CONTACT NUMBER:</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="contactno" value="<?php echo $editrow['contactno']; ?>" id="contactno" oninput="checkContact()" required/></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="modal-table">STATUS:</td>
            <td>
              <select id="status" name="status">
                <option value="" disabled>Select Consumer Status: </option>
                <option value="Active" <?php if($row[ 'status']=='Active' ){ echo "selected"; } ?>> Active</option>
                <option value="Disconnected" <?php if($row[ 'status']=='Disconnected' ){ echo "selected"; } ?>> Disconnected</option>
                <option value="Cut" <?php if($row[ 'status']=='Cut' ){ echo "selected"; } ?>> Cut</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="modal-table">TYPE:</td>
            <td>
              <select id="type" name="type">
                <option value="" disabled>Select Consumer Type: </option>
                <option value="Residential" <?php if($row[ 'type']=='Residential' ){ echo "selected"; } ?>> Residential</option>
                <option value="Commercial" <?php if($row[ 'type']=='Commercial' ){ echo "selected"; } ?>> Commercial</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>


        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="ok" name="update" value="Update" id="edit_client">
      </form>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique. `$("#check_name")` will only select the first match, not the one in the same modal.

Comment: Sorry im new to coding. Thanks for converting my question to code snippet @Barmar. Should I do this $("#check_name<?php echo $row['contactno']; ?>") to make it unique?